# What is the regular expression of the command find -number A www.google.com?

Tags: java, regex

I have seen a lot of useful links in this site about regular expression, I used it to create the following regular expression for the command but it won't work:

```
if(input.matches("find -[0-9]+ A www.(.*).(.*)")){
     System.out.println("m=" +input);
     }
 else{System.out.println("m=" +input);}
```

but it didn't work, what did I do wrong?

Note:

- find -2 A www.google.com should be accepted
- find -2 A www.facebook.com should be accepted
- find -A A www.facebook.com shouldn't be accepted
- find -2 B www.facebook.com shouldn't be accepted

Comment: What is not working? Better you use `"^find -[0-9]+ A www\\.([^.]+)\\.(.+)$"`

Comment: Have you tried your regex [here](https://regex101.com) ?
You should try `find -[0-9]+ A www.(.*)` I think the format will suit you better.
[Example](https://regex101.com/r/zP2mH0/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the to escape the middle dot.

```
find -[0-9]+ A www.(.*)\.(.*)
```

Should do what you want : [test](https://regex101.com/r/zP2mH0/2)